# how to print a string array in a method

Tags: java, arrays, string, methods

I'm trying to do a program that stores names in na array and a method that will print that array however the method is not working and I don't know what is wrong here's my code:

```
//method to print array
public static String printName(String[] name){

      for(int i=0; i<names.length; i++){
              return names[i];
      }
}

public static void main(String[] args){
    String[] names = {"jack"};
    printName(names);
}
```

Comment: You are returning a value and printing nothing. What is your desired output?

Comment: You are not printing anything and also in the first method you are calling "names" array when your argument array is "name"

Comment: A method can only return once. If you `return` in a loop, your loop will end on its first iteration. You could change `printName`'s return type to `void`, and change your `return` to a `System.out.println` call.

Comment: @khelwood I was trying  to use return because my programming teacher said there cant be System.out.print's in methods and we should always use return, maybe I misuderstood

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public static void String printName(String[] names){

    for(int index = 0; index < names.length; index ++)
          System.out.println(names[index]);
}
```

or enhance for loop

```
 public static void String printName(String[] names){

       for(String name : String names)
            System.out.println(name);

 }
```

Comment: I had to correct a few mistankes but it worked thank you very much. @user3773246

Answer (score 0):

You can use `java.util.Arrays`:

```
System.out.println(Arrays.toString(names));
```

Or stream:

```
Arrays.asList(names).stream().forEach(s -> System.out.println(s));
```

Or loop:

```
for(int n: names) {
   System.out.println(n);
}
```

Choose one of these methods and put it here:

```
public static void printName(String[] names) {
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`Arrays.toString(names);` from [java.util.Arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html)